# Error when updating an object in auto-form with meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have checked the docs but I cannot get my head around this. I have an object that I want to update using Auto-Form and Collections2 with meteor.

//Schema

```
Records = new Mongo.Collection('records');

var Schemas = {};


Schemas.Record = new SimpleSchema({
title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title",
    max: 200
},
caption: {
    type: String,
    label: "Caption",
    max: 200
},
text: {
    type: String,
    label: "Detailed text",
    optional: true,
    max: 1000
},
loc: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    autoform: {
        type: "hidden"
    },
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return new Date;
        }
        else if (this.isUpsert) {
            return {
                $setOnInsert: new Date
            };
        }
        else {
            this.unset();
        }
    }
},
updatedBy: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
        return Meteor.userId();
    }
}
});

Records.attachSchema(Schemas.Record);
```

I have a hook so that I assign the object before update

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    insertCommentForm: {
        before: {
            insert: function(doc) {
                doc.commentOn = Template.parentData()._id;
                return doc;
            }
        } 
    },


    updateRecordForm: {
        before: {
            update: function(doc) {
                console.log("storing location data");
                doc.loc = Session.get('geoData');
                console.log(doc.loc);
                return doc;
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

I get this error.

> Uncaught Error: When the modifier option is true, all validation
>   object keys must be operators. Did you forget `$set`?

I don't know how to "$set" with autoform.

Comment: This only seems to be a problem with update.

Comment: Could you post your quickform/autoform tag?

Comment: Here you go... {{#autoForm collection="Records" doc=this id="updateRecordForm" type="update"}}
                    {{> afQuickField name='title'}}
                    {{> afQuickField name='caption'}}
                    {{> afQuickField name='text' rows=6}}
                    {{> afQuickField name='loc' }}

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                {{/autoForm}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you are trying to update a document in Mongo, when you want to update only certain fields, you will use the `$set` modifier.

`Records.update({ _id: 1 }, { $set: { loc: { lat: 12, lng: 75 } } })`

The above would update only the `loc` value.

`Records.update({ _id: 1 }, { loc: { lat: 12, lng: 75 } })`

The above would remove all other keys and the record will only have the `_id` and the `loc`.

Your hook will have to set the `loc` key in `doc.$set`.

Please update your hook with the following code and it should work:

```
updateRecordForm: {
    before: {
        update: function(doc) {
            console.log("storing location data", doc);
            doc.$set.loc = Session.get('geoData');
            return doc;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Like to know how to access nested Object in doc.$set . For example doc.$set.profile.name did not work.

Comment: Stuck in a similar situation. How do we do a doc.$set on nested fields?